# MSAL requests HTTP page and a "Mixed Content" error is thrown

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I am playing a bit with MSAL for auth operations with Azure B2C. For some reason it tries to redirect the user to the HTTP endpoint instead of HTTPS one while acquiring token with popup. My app has HTTPS redirect URL in B2C. The MSAL configuration has the same redirect URL set up. I can't find any place where MSAL or B2C would have any HTTP endpoint configured. The error is:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://MYPAGE.com' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure frame 'http://MYPAGE.com/#error=interaction_required&error_description=AADB2C90077%3a+User+does+not+have+an+existing+session+and+request+prompt+parameter+has+a+value+of+%27None%27.%0d%0aCorrelation+ID%3a+302a0615-b431-4a4d-9104-f58e3a8229ab%0d%0aTimestamp%3a+2020-08-10+06%3a46%3a11Z%0d%0a&state=eyJpZCI6IjI0Y23jYTJkLWQxMjUtNGZlNy05NjBjLWI0NTkwNWE5NWJlYyIsInRzIjoxNTk3MDQxOTc0LCJtZXRob2QiOiJzaWxlbnRJbnRlcmFjdGlvbiJ9'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Interestingly, in the end the auth works, however, with that error it takes more time to load the popup that acquires the access token.

When I run my site locally on http://localhost:8000 this problem does not occur at all (since it's http anyway) and token is acquired much faster.

Comment: May I know what us your app type (Eg: AngularJS, JS etc)? Also, May I know which version of msal.js you are using and if possible share the URL generated and configuration done in Azure App Portal.

Comment: @RohitPrasad It is vanilla JavaScript. MSAL is of version 1.3.1. Well, the configuration is with enabled implicit flow, the redirect URL is https://MYPAGE.com (I do not want to share an actual domain, but the crucial point is that it's HTTPS). Other than that, no other things were configured.

Comment: I don't want the actual URL. I just want to know when you launch the login what is the difference in URLs compared to local as you mentioned that locally everything is working fine.  Can you check if any issue showing in console (Enable Preserve log to have all the logs).

Comment: Locally there is no error, because I use HTTP: //localhost locally, so there is no chance to have a Mixed Content

Comment: Have you tried to put `https://YOURPAGE.com` into the address bar in your browser like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42639087/13308381)?

Comment: @PamelaPeng Yes, my page is truly served via HTTPS. I see the green lock :)

Comment: Humm, I'm sorry, I meant this URL: `https://YOURPAGE.com/#error=interaction_required&error_description=AADB2C90077%3a+User+does+not+have+an+existing+session+and+request+prompt+parameter+has+a+value+of+%27None%27.%0d%0aCorrelation+ID%3a+302a0615-b431-4a4d-9104-f58e3a8229ab%0d%0aTimestamp%3a+2020-08-10+06%3a46%3a11Z%0d%0a&state=eyJpZCI6IjI0Y23jYTJkLWQxMjUtNGZlNy05NjBjLWI0NTkwNWE5NWJlYyIsInRzIjoxNTk3MDQxOTc0LCJtZXRob2QiOiJzaWxlbnRJbnRlcmFjdGlvbiJ9`. And this is a similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42639087/13308381).

Comment: @PamelaPeng Yep, checked this one too. It stays on HTTPS.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error that you faced. And I find a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48700852/13308381) that adding following code to the HTML page `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests"> `. Hope it helps.